# Timber Twig WebP compression level when converting images

Tags: wordpress, webp, timber

I started using the `towebp` filter to convert images into webp format - very excited about that feature by the way :) While the images looked quite fine in several implementations I just compared the original output of an uploaded image to the converted one and the webp version has much less sharpness. In this case the image is skaled up a little bit but it the same for the original version..

So my question is: **can we adjust the webp-quality** (compression level) **when using the |towebp filter**?

And if so - how?

**Edit:**
I just tried to call the filter and passing a numer like:

```
data-srcset="{{ image_item.src|resize(imgWidthDesktop)|towebp(100) }}"
```

in hope targeting the quality level. The new generated file has a bigger filesize so I guess it works like that. Still the original image is a little bit more crisp but has double the filesize even when setting 100% webp quality level.

If this is the way to config webp quality level it should be mentioned in the image cookbook:
https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/cookbook-images/

Can someone confirm that this is the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if we look at source code we can see a `$quality` argument.

[See](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/lib/Image/Operation/ToWebp.php#L14)

The default quality is [80](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/lib/ImageHelper.php#L216)

Comment: I found the 80% default too but I didn’d get the mapping from calling the filter in twig file to the final method. Strange this is not documented in the otherwise awesome docs.

Comment: So is it possible to adjust this in the twig filter?

Comment: @Bryce Yes it is possible. Keep in mind that images that are already converted are not re-converted after only setting a new compression level. You have to delete them first.